# How to construct counterexamples of spaces which satisfy some separation axioms?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I want to know some counterexamples of spaces which satisfy some separation axioms.For example, the counterexample for a space which doesn't satisfy $T_0$,$T_3$ and $T_4$ axioms.

Is there a more efficient way to construct these counterexamples?

Thank you!

Comment: You might try small finite sets, and try on paper to partition into "open sets" to get the desired property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following statement

> If topological spaces $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$ satisfy $\mathrm{T}_k$ axiom for all $i\in I$, where $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, then $\sqcup_{i\in I}(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$ with the disjoint union topology also satisfies $\mathrm{T}_k$ axiom.

Then you will have something like this.
[The examples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6mWH.png)

Thus you only need to consider the cofinite topological spaces, the Sierpinski topological space, the trivial topological space, the Moore topological space, the metric space, the half-disc topological space.

The above topological spaces could be easily found in any textbook, or on wikipedia.